# Module Not Found Error But I Installed The Library

Tags: python, error-handling

My program is not working. I imported the psycopg2 library from the Windows Terminal, and after installing I activated Python in the terminal itself. I imported the library, it said there was a ModuleNotFoundError. This is the screen shot I took:

[image: Screenshot ==>]

Please note: The photo was taken after downloading once. That is why it says "already satisfied".

I was expecting it to work without and error.

Comment: I think you installed it in conda, not in your main python installation. Try `python -m pip install psycopg2`, this should install it to be usable with python.